# How to create array and pass them in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like to pass fetched data like following `array`.

```
 { category: ['Animals','Vehicles']

   difficulty: ['easy','medium']
 }
```

I tried something like following, `getCategory.push(quiz.getCategory(2)),`

But I encountered following errors.

`Unexpected token .`

I confused how to pass array like data.

If someone has opinon,please let me know.

Thanks

```
const API_KEY="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=multiple";
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Quiz=require("../public/javascripts/quiz");


module.exports={
    getQuiz:function(resp){
      fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => { const quiz = new Quiz(json); 
            resp.send({
                getCategory:quiz.getCategory(1),
                getCategory.push(quiz.getCategory(2)),
                getDifficulty:quiz.getDifficulty(1),
                getDifficulty.push(quiz.getDifficulty(2))
  
            });
        });
    }
};
```

My class is following.

```
class Quiz {
    constructor(quizData){
        this._quizzes = quizData.results;
        this._correctAnswersNum = 0;
    }
    
    getNumOfQuiz(){
        return this._quizzes.length;
    }
    
    getCategory(index){
        return this._quizzes[index-1].category;
    }
    getDifficulty(index){
        return this._quizzes[index-1].difficulty;
    }
}
module.exports = Quiz;
```

`fetch(API_KEY)` returned something like following.

```
 results: 
   [ { category: 'Animals',
       type: 'multiple',
       difficulty: 'easy',
       question: 'What do you call a baby bat?',
       correct_answer: 'Pup',
       incorrect_answers: [Array] },
     { category: 'Vehicles',
       type: 'multiple',
       difficulty: 'medium',
       question: 'Which supercar company is from Sweden?',
       correct_answer: 'Koenigsegg',
       incorrect_answers: [Array] },
     { category: 'Entertainment: Board Games',
       type: 'multiple',
       difficulty: 'hard',
       question: 'Which board game was first released on February 6th, 1935?',
       correct_answer: 'Monopoly',
       incorrect_answers: [Array] }]
```

Comment: Thanks. As I am not familiar ,I edited the question.  I tried to transform output result.thanks

Comment: you need to send array as response ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see how exactly we need to use the Class methods in this implementation..
But we can go as follows.

This is the data we are receiving

```
const data = [ { category: 'Animals',
       type: 'multiple',
       difficulty: 'easy',
       question: 'What do you call a baby bat?',
       correct_answer: 'Pup',
       incorrect_answers: [Array] },
     { category: 'Vehicles',
       type: 'multiple',
       difficulty: 'medium',
       question: 'Which supercar company is from Sweden?',
       correct_answer: 'Koenigsegg',
       incorrect_answers: [Array] },
     { category: 'Entertainment: Board Games',
       type: 'multiple',
       difficulty: 'hard',
       question: 'Which board game was first released on February 6th, 1935?',
       correct_answer: 'Monopoly',
       incorrect_answers: [Array] }];
```

The data structure we want to send as in response.

```
const finalResponse = {
  category : [],
  difficulty : [] 
}
```

Looping over actual data, and collect the data in `finalResponse`. May be if you already know the `index` of data you can make the use if `Class` as mentioned in question. For now we have used `data` array prototype method `forEach` to loop over each datum as shown below.

```
data.forEach(function({category, difficulty}){
    finalResponse.category.push(category);
    finalResponse.category.push(difficulty);
})
```

finally send the collected data as response

```
res.send(finalResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 (quick fix):

```
const API_KEY="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=multiple";
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Quiz=require("../public/javascripts/quiz");


module.exports={
    getQuiz:function(resp){
      fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => { const quiz = new Quiz(json); 
            resp.send({
                getCategory:[quiz.getCategory(1), quiz.getCategory(2)],
                getDifficulty:[quiz.getDifficulty(1),quiz.getDifficulty(2)]
  
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Answer 2 (correct way):

- class Quiz : introduce new method to get array | getPropArray() // I'm bad at naming

```
class Quiz {
    constructor(quizData){
        this._quizzes = quizData.results;
        this._correctAnswersNum = 0;
    }
    
    getNumOfQuiz(){
        return this._quizzes.length;
    }
    
    getCategory(index){
        return this._quizzes[index-1].category;
    }
    getDifficulty(index){
        return this._quizzes[index-1].difficulty;
    }
    /**
    * get array of prop (property) 
    * @param {string} prop
    * @param {number} start
    * @param {number} end
    */
    getPropArray(prop, start=1, end=this._quizzes.length){
        let res = [];
        for (let i=start-1; i<=end-1; i++){
             res.push(this._quizzes[i][prop]);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
module.exports = Quiz;
```

now you can add new property to your response if you want, idk what logic you wanna use to choose result[index] but here^ you can apply a range.

```
const API_KEY="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=multiple";
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Quiz=require("../public/javascripts/quiz");


module.exports={
    getQuiz:function(resp){
      fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => { const quiz = new Quiz(json); 
            resp.send({
                getCategory: quiz.getPropArray('category' ),
                getDifficulty: quiz.getPropArray('difficulty')
            });
        });
    }
};
```